# Bulk update relations in Neo4J using Cypher (with deletion & creation of relations)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to bulk update a list of relations between 2 sets of nodes.

In the process, some relations are going to get deleted, some are going to remain, and others are going to be created.

This is an example data structure (left for before, right for after)

[image]

To achieve this in a single query, this is the algorithm I've found

```
 1. MATCH (f:Foo)-[r]-(Bar) WHERE id(f)=1
 2. SET r.delete = true
 3. UNWIND [2, 3, 4] as $node_id
 4.   MERGE (f)-[r2]-(b:Bar) WHERE id(b)=$node_id
 5.   SET r2.delete = false
 6. MATCH (Foo)-[r3:{delete: true}]-()
 7. DELETE r3
```

Is there a more concise / efficient way to do this ? (I need to do it for multiple relations from a single Foo node in one pass and that makes for some quite hefty queries). I searched for this in apoc library but could not find a function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the spurious `delete` property. Assuming that you pass the native ID of `f` and a list of the IDs of the desired `Bar` nodes as the [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) `$fId` and `$barIds`, you can do this:

```
MATCH (f:Foo) WHERE ID(f) = $fId
FOREACH(r IN [(f)-[rel:X]->(:Bar)|rel] |
  DELETE r
)
WITH f
MATCH (b:Bar) WHERE ID(b) IN $barIds
MERGE (f)-[:X]->(b)
```

Note that the `MERGE` of a relationship requires a relationship type, so I arbitrarily used `X` as the type.